# Subprocess.Popen: How to pass arguments without whitespace

Tags: python, subprocess

Mighty people of Stackoverflow,

I want to execute

```
./namecoind name_new d/<name>
```

in a Python script with subprocess.popen where 'name' is a variable within the script. There are no spaces allowed between 'd/' and the variable. I tried this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./namecoind", "name_new", "d/", domainname])
```

but this does not work, because this adds an ws between d/ and 'domainname'.

So, what to?

Thanks in advance!

Steffen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespace doesn't enter the picture; `subprocess.Popen` doesn't go through the shell if you pass it a list (as opposed to a string), so it is not subject to splitting of the command line on whitespace. The argument simply need to be sent as a single list item:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./namecoind", "name_new", "d/" + domainname])
```